# How do I check the value of a token?

Tags: webforms

How do I validate a webform token in the WYSIWYG using PHP Filter format?

I have enabled PHP Filter and tried a simple conditional if statement but return an error.

```
Eg: if ([submission:values:keyname] == 'Test') print 'hi';
```

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ']' in
/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code on line 2**

But if I print `[submission:values:keyname]` it will return `Test`

**Edit**
I ended up using below code which solve my problem.

```
$sid = 2;
$submission = webform_get_submissions(array('sid' => $sid));
$nid = $submission[$sid]->nid;

$submission = webform_get_submission($nid, $sid);
$data = $submission->data;
$node = node_load($sid);
$components = $node->webform['components'];
$labels = array();
foreach ($components as $key => $component) {
  $labels[$key] = $component['form_key'];
}
$fields = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $values) {
  $fields[$labels[$key]] = $values[0];
}
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
  print $key .':'.$value;
}
```

Comment: Try putting it in quotes maybe? `if ('[submission:values:keyname]'...`. Sounds like it's being parsed before the string replacement, though, so you might be forced into doing this the proper way

Comment: If i put quotes around it the error goes away but the token never get evaluated. Meaning `'[submission:values:keyname]'` only equal to '[submission:values:keyname]'. It becomes string instead of shortcode.

Comment: Also what do you mean by proper way? Can you explain/guide me on how to do it?